# JVM goes to sleep when running shell script consicutively

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, jvm

I have several shell scripts which need to be run one after the other and Java need to get error and output stream. I want to make sure each shell is executed only when previous one has finished. I tried this and it is working fine in many conditions. But some shell scripts are more than 10 to 50MB. When I execute this, JVM hangs. I tried both ProcessBuilder and Runtime. Both provided same results. I think JVM goes to exit state. The shell script is running in normal terminal when I run it. It is making some problem only when ran from Java. I have tried two types of code, as given below.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
String[] envp = {"WORK_HOME="+Cisma.constant.getWork_home_directory(),                      "BUILD_DIR="+Cisma.constant.getWork_home_directory()+"verif/compile/build"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, envp); //hangs in this line
p.waitFor();
result.add(Output, getOutput(p));
result.add(Error, getError(p));
System.out.println(commands[0]+"End "+p.exitValue()); //printing 0, for our hang state it does not go to this line
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
p.destroy();
```

another method I used is,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.directory(new File(working_directory));
pb.environment().put("WORK_HOME", Cisma.constant.getWork_home_directory());
pb.environment().put("BUILD_DIR", Cisma.constant.getWork_home_directory()+"verif/compile/build");
//pb.inheritIO(); // tried but did not work
//File f = new File ("temp");
//pb.redirectError(f);
//File o = new File ("temp1");
//pb.redirectOutput(o);
Process p = pb.start(); // hangs in this line
p.getOutputStream().flush();
p.waitFor();
p.destroy();
```

My Project Name is CISMA_Regression main is in com.cisma.Cisma

```
src/apb_test17% /bin/ps -edf | grep java
jeevan    5263  5262  7 11:47 ?        00:03:13 /usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /home/jeevan/Application/eclips
jeevan    7818  5263  0 12:21 ?        00:00:03 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 -classpath /home/jeevan/workspace/CISMA_Regression/target
jeevan    9751  6681  0 12:29 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
src/apb_test17% top -b -n1 | grep 5263
 5263 jeevan    20   0 6016600 675364  54836 S 0.000 8.296   3:14.08 java
src/apb_test17% ps -edf | grep java
jeevan    5263  5262  5 11:47 ?        00:03:35 /usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaV
jeevan    7818  5263  0 12:21 ?        00:00:04 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java -Df
jeevan   10324  6681  0 12:50 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Can some one help me out?

Comment: Check how much memory java consumes. If it consumes more memory try to increase the memory by using jvm flags.

Comment: So it still does not work if you redirect both standard output and error output of the process as in the commented code in your second method? Without redirection (as in your first block of code) this would be perfectly normal to happen.

Comment: @Shriram: how to do that in Linux?

Comment: @PhilippWendler: I tried all sorts of redirection, none of them worked.

Comment: Are you sure it hangs in the `start` method and not in `waitFor`? How did you check this? (You can use `jstack <pid>` on the command line to get a stack trace.)

Comment: Is the shell script actually started? Can you see it with `ps`? Can you run a different, simple, command to check if it is a problem with your script only? (For example, run `/bin/echo foo`.)

Comment: @PhilippWendler: My shell script deletes a particular file at first and creates a new file instead of it. It deletes the file and creates new one. But that file is emply nothing is getting written there. Before that Java stops. I tried waitfor with a time out, and it goes to next file and pauses.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: that shell script is running inside a process builder, hence it doesn't have a seperate process id. My java code and it has the same process id, hence I am unable to check that.

Comment: No, that is wrong. A `ProcessBuilder` is just another way for `Runtime.exec`, it does not change anything after the process was started. The process will still be a regular Linux process with a separate PID.

Comment: If that it true, then how come the ProcessBuilder knows, how and when the shell script has terminated? I am unable to find a seperate process id.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` does not know when the process was terminated, because after `start`, the `ProcessBuilder` does not do anything. The `Process` instance you get from `start` knows this, because inside the `waitFor` method it asks the OS whether the process with the PID it has stored was terminated.

Comment: I suggest you debug this a little bit more with the hints I have given and add the necessary information to the question by editing it. Otherwise people cannot help you. A stack trace would be helpful, for example, whether it works with different commands, whether the command produces output or needs input etc.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: still no processID related to it found, I have checked it again.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: can u please give me a hint, how could I debug further in?

Comment: I already mentioned this: run `jstack` with the Java PID to get a strack trace. Try a different command, preferably a trivial one like `/bin/echo foo`. Make sure redirection of output and error works. Make sure your command does not expect any input.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: I found something that my shell is doing a System diff with two files which is around 600 to 700KB. This is the place it is hanging. When I removed that diff, it is running properly. Can't Java do a system diff using ProcessBuilder?

Comment: Jeevan, please add all additional information to your question by editing it. Surely Java can call `diff` like any other program. I heavily suspect this is blocked because you did not redirect the output of the process appropriately. Please create a full, compilable, and runnable example such that others can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @PhilippWendler: It works now. Thanks for your help. 
Make sure if the shell doesn't read large files internally. If it does, pass the file through Java. For example in diff there is a library called Java Diff Utils https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage . I used those library. Using ProcessBuilder, you have limitation with Java memory in running large shell scripts.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: Please post this answer, stackoverflow has blocked me from answering any questions. Thanks

Comment: Using a Java library might make sense, but there is surely no problem with doing the same shell-based, if done correctly, and there won't be a memory problem. Thus this is no answer to the problem.

Comment: But it could be considered as one solution, I am unable to find any other. Any way thanks for your help @PhilippWendler

Comment: @PhilippWendler: I think it is a bug in Java. We may need to report. 
Can you vote me please, StackOverflow had blocked me from many features like reply, etc.

Comment: @Jeevan for an upvote you would need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (hint: you would absolutely need that for a bugreport, too)

Answer (score 0):

check your memory by jconsole which will be available in jdk. 
Increase your jvm by using the following commands.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

links [how to find memory in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/find-out-your-java-heap-memory-size/)

Comment: I doubt that this is a problem related to the heap or stack size of the JVM, because starting a process does not consume a lot of memory unless you are reading in lots of output from the process, which does not happen if output is redirected to a file.

Comment: @PhilippWendler: I think the output, input and error stream are overflowing.

Comment: @Jeevan Yes, this would be expected and would show this problem, but it will not happen if you redirect them to a file (and redirection to a file does not need memory in the JVM). The input stream cannot overflow until you write something into it from Java.

Comment: @PhillippWender: Is there a chance to redirect all to NULL ?

Comment: You should be able to do this by using `new File("/dev/null")`, but any other file would be ok, too (and you could check what gets written to that file).